# Low Quality Review failure... I don't understand

Tags: support, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

So I failed a review... again. And again, I don't understand why.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/19023626

[image]

---

This answer does **nothing** to actually answer the question about rectangle packing, going into memories about a related, also unsolved problem, then posting a **link** to something that **might** contain an answer.

If that is not the definition of "Link only" then I don't know what is.

But to my surprise... SO wants me to click "Looks good". What do we do about this? Can we remove it from the audits please? Or did I miss something important about that post?

Comment: I would for sure also failed that one. Clear link only answer for me.

Comment: The lack of downvotes on things like these is always going to trip the automatic audit selection process. Even after having found this in review, and even after having had additional exposure in meta, no down-votes. So it appears it shouldn't be deleted after all.

Comment: i mean... that's far from link only... Maybe not useful, but that's not a flag reason.

Comment: @KevinB:  The answer is quite literally link-only.  There's noise about them being a student, there's a link, then there's giving any reader a vague pointer into "special cases" which may or may not exist (and I have my doubts about its existence).  I'd have proudly failed this audit as well, honestly...

Comment: And still, that post got yet another upvote since this question got posted.  If users are willing to flag, but not willing to downvote, it will always be hard for an automatic selection system to work reliably.

Comment: Hmya, it is the common difference between a popular and a correct answer.  He was the first one to point out what kind of trouble the OP is in for.  JATothrim's answer addresses it as well but was posted 2 days later.  Let's not get rid of correct answers.

Comment: Is that question even closable? It was edited by a mod so I guess not? Reads like homework to me (OP even admits they hadn't tried to solve it on their own)

Comment: Failed audit... welcome to the club.

Comment: I probably would have failed too. The non-link portion, if edited to remove the fluff we normally remove would boil down to "This *was thought to be* an unsolvable problem, but that might have changed. [link]."  Which...is not really an answer. It's *part* of one, but the rest of the post is just a link. That link could say *anything* about the problem.

Comment: The "failed audit" page should have some option to click on when you think the audit is faulty.

Comment: @immibis For the "known good" audits, it already does, as I describe in my answer.

Comment: @Draco18s Not even that. The "answer" says "The same problem with an added dimension was thought to be unsolvable in the past" (cube vs rectangle, 3d vs 2d). It does not get less helpful. That's like saying "Flight was thought unsolvable in the past" to a question on how to drive a car to Paris. While undoubtedly true, it does *nothing* to answer the question. Not even grammatically.

Comment: "Please click Looks Good" ? but there's just "Looks OK".

Comment: an option no one mentioned yet is to vote the _question_ down and close. Closing the question would have the effect of answer dropping off from "known good" audits (iirc these answers are picked only from open positive score questions)

Comment: @immibis I could see that resulting in most failed audits clicking that option

Answer (score 6):

Yeah, that's a pretty poor answer.  It probably shouldn't have been selected as an audit (and by now it won't be, since a bunch of people have downvoted it), but that's really the fault of the six users who upvoted it, and the several more who presumably saw it and *didn't* downvote it.

All that said, it probably does *not* deserve to be deleted, since it does *sort of* make an attempt to answer the question, and could potentially even be of some use to someone trying to solve the same problem.  So IMO voting to "Recommend Delete" was also kind of a bad call.

When I come across this kind of a borderline answer in review, what I usually do is:

1. Middle-click the "link" in the sidebar to open the answer in a new tab.
2. Downvote the answer in the new tab.
3. After downvoting, select either "Looks OK" or "Skip" and move on.

This gets the answer handled in the way bad but still technically valid answers *should* be handled, i.e. by downvoting, not deletion.  As a useful side effect, it will also reveal any badly selected audits and guarantee that those answers will not be chosen as an audit ever again.

Comment: It would be better to move it to a comment on the question, and then delete it. It's ludicrous that it has now garnered a net +90 rep, when you compare it to some of the other answers to the question. Six of the upvotes were given after it received attention here. It's episodes like this that underline just how utterly pointless the review process can be at times.

Answer (score 3):

> This answer does nothing to actually answer the question

It states that they believe the problem is not solvable, although they do mention that it's possible that the question author may be a special case of the problem that makes it solvable, unlike the general case.  They've also indicated that they're not very confident in their answer.

You may think that that's a *bad* answer, or a wrong answer, or an incomplete answer, but it is trying to answer the question.  It's saying that they don't think there is a solution.  That's an answer, even if it's wrong, and even if they're unsure about it.

> If that is not the definition of "Link only" then I don't know what is.

The definition of "link only" is an answer that only has a link, rather than an answer that you think is a bad answer that also happens to contain a link in it.

> What do we do about this?

If you think that the answer is wrong, or bad, you can downvote it.  You can also comment on how you think the author might be able to improve the answer.  But it's still attempting to answer the question, so it's not Not An Answer.

> Can we remove it from the audits please?

*You* can, if you really feel that it's not an example of a good post, by as mentioned above, downvoting it to indicate that you don't think it's a high quality answer.  You don't need anyone else to do it for you.

Comment: Why should this be served in an answer rather than a comment?  That is to say, would the answer lose any power or be out of place if it were transferred to a comment instead?

Comment: @Makoto It's an attempt to answer the question.  Comments are the place where you provide temporary information used to improve a post, not where you post an answer to the question, or even where you post *bad* answers to a question.  This post is not suggesting some improvement to the question, and so it doesn't make sense as a comment.  Again, if you think that this is not a *good* answer, you can vote accordingly.  That doesn't make it a comment.

Comment: How is "This is a hard problem but you might have luck and be in a special case. But I'm not sure. For more information read this" an answer to "How do I solve problem X". I could leave an almost identical answer to every algorithmic question on the site. When the link dies it does not serve any purpose except for saying that the problem might be hard to solve.

Comment: @BDL  It doesn't say it's a hard problem, it says it's an unsolvable problem.  Big difference.  Saying you think a problem is hard is indeed pointless.  Saying a problem is *unsolvable* is an answer.  This is an answer *even if you ignore the link entirely*.  If you think that it's not a *useful* answer to the question (perhaps because you think it's not true), you can downvote it.  That doesn't mean it's not trying to answer the question, it just means you don't think it *succeeded* in answering the question.

Comment: @BDL "When the link dies it does not serve any purpose except for saying that the problem might be hard to solve" -- In any case, one possible improvement with respect to that is adding the title and author of the thesis to the link, so that it would be possible to go looking for it if the link ever died.

Comment: @Servy: I disagree: It says that **cube** packing is impossible to solve. The question asks about **rectangle** packing.

Comment: @BDL Hence why they said they weren't sure whether or not it applied or not.  If you feel that makes the answer not useful, again, you're free to reflect that opinion.  That doesn't make it not an attempt to answer the question.  At most it makes it a failed attempt at answering the question, which still isn't NAA.  If you think an answer is *wrong*, then downvote it, don't flag it as NAA, and don't try to delete it from review.  If you do, you'll continue to fail audits.

Comment: @Servy The answer doesn't say anything about cube packing applying to rectangle packing or not. It doesn't take a stand on the possibility/impossibility of rectangle packing whatsoever, by my reading. If it did, I would agree with you, but as it stands, that answer reads to me as "Some other vaguely related problem is unsolvable. Check this link for your problem"

Comment: @mbrig It's saying, "The generalized version of the problem you're trying to solve is unsolvable.  Whether or not this problem becomes solvable as a result of your more specific constraints is something I'm unsure of."  That's an attempt answer to the question (even i you don't think it's good enough).

Comment: @Servy The 3D problem (cubioids) is not a generalized version of the 2D, it borders on being an entirely different topology problem. The question is then asking to solve an even more specialized version (perfect rectangles) of that (simpler) problem.

Comment: @mbrig That's a fantastic argument for explaining why you think that the answer is not a good answer to the question.  That doesn't mean it's not an attempt to answer the question, it just means you think it *fails* to answer the question.  By all means, reflect your viewpoint with a downvote.  That doesn't mean the post isn't an answer.  You are arguing the technical merits of the answer, and whether or not it *succeeds* in answering the question, not whether or not it is an *attempt* to answer the question, which is something that is entirely unrelated to the answer's technical merits.

Comment: @Servy I mean, its an argument for why the answer is answering a substantially different question. An answer to an algorithmic question that said "the halting problem is unsolvable, see this link for research on parsing nested regexes" is not just poor quality in my mind, its not an answer at all.

Comment: @mbrig They apparently didn't consider it a substantively different question, given that they felt it appropriate to post the answer, and apparently neither did all of the people that read the answer and upvoted it.  If you do, you're free to indicate that their answer is not useful.  Again, you arguing that someone has *failed* to answer the question doesn't make a post not an answer.  It simply doesn't *matter* how right you are about the technical merits of how good the answer is.  No one is disputing that.  But that doesn't make it *not an attempt to answer the question*.

Comment: @Servy By that logic, all flags are meaningless. I'm sure the 1000s of deleted questions and answers SO gets a day "considered themselves" to be on-topic/high-quality/attempts to answer the question. What they consider themselves as is irrelevant if they are wrong. I'm not disputing the technical merits of the answer. I disagree with you that it is an attempt to answer the question, because it is an answer to a different question. Please stop assuming that what I am trying to argue agrees with your viewpoint.

Comment: @Servy The answer does not say "this is an unsolvable problem" it says "This was thought to be an unsolvable problem." Note the key words "thought" and "was." It either is--or it isn't--unsolvable, and the author even *mentions that they did not do the research to find out.* Their only supporting evidence for the (un)solvability is a link...which could say anything.

Comment: @Draco18s It doesn't even say that. It says that a substantially different (in my view) problem is unsolvable, then links to research which deals with the question OP actually asked.

Comment: @mbrig True, it does say that. But that is ignorable because "Princess Celestia is a pony" does not qualify as Not An Answer, so "This other problem that's sorta related might be unsolvable" is also not NAA, so we have to assume that the text of the post is actually trying to solve the problem.

Comment: @mbrig The close reasons for posts being on topic doesn't say, "the author of the question thinks that the question is on topic".  The spam flag doesn't say, "the author of this post doesn't consider this spam", and so on, for every possible flag reason *except*, not an answer.  A post is Not An Answer *when it is not an attempt to answer the question*.  So no, your logic is flawed, and this *doesn't* apply to the other flag reasons, just whether or not an answer is an answer.

Comment: Your continued reasoning for how the answer *fails* to answer the question doesn't make it not an answer.  Saying that it doesn't *succeed* in answering the question doesn't mean it's Not An Answer.  That doesn't make it not an *attempt* to answer the question, it makes it a *failed* attempt to answer the question.

Comment: @Draco18s That doesn't make it not an answer.  It's a great argument for why you think it's not a *good* answer.  But someone being unsure of their answer doesn't mean it's not an answer.

Comment: @Servy I didn't say it was NAA (I even said the opposite: it is **not** NAA), I said that it's a *link only* answer because the non-link portion is little more than fluff to say "your answer is here [link]".

Comment: @Draco18s There is no "link only" flag.  An answer that's *actually* just a link *is* NAA.  This answer *does* provide an attempt to answer the question, even when ignoring the link entirely.  The rest of the answer *isn't* just saying that the answer is in the link, the answer is saying that the think the problem is likely unsolvable.  *That's an answer*.  Whether you think it's correct (or useful) is something to reflect with an up/down vote.

Comment: @Servy, perhaps I should start answering questions with boldly unformed opinions backed up by irrelevant mathematics and quotes from my father's PhD dissertation (*Congress and Israel*) and my sister's (*Using a Resiliency Framework to Examine Natural Mentoring Relationships and the Coping Efficacy as Buffers of the Negative Impact of Stressors on Academic Outcomes in Urban, Low-Income Ethnic Minority Youth*). If I do have such a lapse in judgement, I hope the answers will be deleted to protect my reputation.

Comment: A *failed* attempt is saying "As cube is unsolvable (link to wikipedia), that means that rectangle, a specific subset of the problem, is unsolvable, too". That would be *wrong*, but an attempt to answer. But the answer does not say *anything* about what the fact that cube is thought to be unsolvable means for the question at hand. The answer does literally not address the question on how to solve this for rectangles. Not even in a wrong way, saying it's impossible. The fact that the algorithm for cubes and rectangles must be somehow connected is *your interpretation*. It does not say so.

Comment: We disagree on basically anything we both comment on, so I thought you'd get a good laugh out of [this](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7753/are-we-comfortable-with-our-current-position-on-deleting-general-answers-to-syst/7777#7777) post of mine over at another SE where I'm basically taking the position you defend here and have all the mods disagree with me. Oh the irony.

Comment: @dfeuer If you're *knowingly* going around posting information that's off topic in which you are clearly not *intending* to answer the question, then that's Not An Answer.  That's just you trolling.  If you *actually think* that your father's PhD dissertation is the answer to a given question, even if you're wrong, then that's still an answer.  People can tell the difference between a sincere but incorrect answer and someone who's actively trolling.  People always try to bring that up as an argument for why all wrong answers should be NAA, but it's just not a problem for the system to handle.

Comment: @nvoigt If you think the answer *fails* to properly answer the question at hand, that's fine.  You're more than welcome to reflect that opinion with a downvote.  Again, I'm not arguing that the answerer has *succeeded* in answering the question, I'm arguing that they have *attempted* to answer the question. The NAA flag is for things like requests for clarification, posting new questions as answers, things that should have been edits to the question, etc., not something that someone felt was an answer that you don't think is good enough. There are tools to deal with said answers, just not NAA.

Comment: I'm not sure you read my comment. *Failing* means an answer is provided and it's wrong. NAA means it does not answer the question. If you remove the link, the remainder *does literally not answer the question*. The remainder is an interesting fact. Could be an interesting comment. Could even be edited into an answer if the author explains how that fact relates to the question. That's why this answer is "link only". Without the link, it's not an answer. There is nothing factually wrong when you remove the link, but what is left is literally not answering the question.

Comment: @nvoigt No.  Failing to answer the question means that the question doesn't succeed in answering the question.  There are lots of ways you can fail to answer the question.  Being wrong is one of them.  Misunderstanding the question, and as a result, posting an answer that doesn't answer the *actual* question, is another.  Providing an *incomplete* (but not incorrect) answer is yet another way.  No, NAA doesn't mean that the answer doesn't *succeed* in answering the question, it means it doesn't *attempt* to answer the question.

Comment: Well, in my opinion, the only *attempt* was the link. Removing that, the remainder is an interesting comment without an attempt at answering. Apparently you don't think so, so lets agree to disagree on that.

Comment: @Servy "If you're knowingly going around posting information that's off topic in which you are clearly not intending to answer the question, then that's Not An Answer. That's just you trolling." Really? So then "But someone being unsure of their answer doesn't mean it's not an answer" means I can post answers that are patently ridiculous, then dispute all NAA flags raised on them because I claim to be "unsure", and those disputes must be upheld. This kind of dogmatic, nonsensical idiocy - and the people like you who enable it - is the exact reason why Stack Overflow has a quality problem.

Comment: @IanKemp If they're patently ridiculous, then no, we know you're not unsure.  The example that I was responded to is a case where you can very clearly demonstrate that the author of the answer knew full well that they were not attempting to answer the question.  **NAA flags are not the mechanism for judging the quality of answers**.  If you're considering the quality of an answer then **you are doing something wrong if you're flagging it as NAA, or marking it for deleting in review**.  Those flags exist to remove posts that *aren't answers*, not answers that you don't think are high quality.

Comment: @IanKemp If you feel that an answer is not of sufficiently high quality *downvote it*. That is the mechanism in place to judge the quality of answers.  Abusing moderation tools to claim that *an answer to the question* isn't an answer, when you know that it is, just because you think it's not a *quality* answer, is, frankly, how you'll end up having those moderation tools taken away.  You already have a perfectly good tool for judging the quality of  posts.  Use it, if you care about quality.