# First-Post review audit failure and Review Ban

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits, link-only-answers, review-suspension

Recently I've reviewed the **First Post** review queue. However, I failed to pass an audit https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/19048874

I reviewed it as *No Action Needed*. But the audit suggests that I should flag this answer as *link-only*. However, even after I got this failure, I couldn't understand why this answer should be flagged as *link-only*.

This answer certainly has an explanation, not very long but in a reasonable length, which looks related to the question as well. Thus it's not *link-only*. Moreover, when I was reviewing, I looked at the right side status, the question has only 2 answers and without accepted answer.

I'm not an expert of the question itself, but based on the information appearing in this review task, I think it's very likely that this answer could be helpful to OP or someone else. It shouldn't be flagged or deleted.

This wasn't the first time when I failed the **First Post** audit. I failed on some *very-low-quality* audit before with the similar reason(i.e. after that I still didn't agree the audit is *very-low-quality*).

So this time I got banned from review. It seems this review ban has impact not only on *First Post*, it even rejects me from approving other's edit. However, I have done many review tasks in *close-vote*, *suggested-edit* and *low-quality*, without any failure. The only failures are in **First Post**.

Finally, my questions are:

- Is the audit linked above a justifiable *link-only* answer ? Especially when it is used as an **audit** to activate review ban.
- If the goal of the audit is to avoid robot-reviewing, is it reasonable to impose a review ban **for all review tasks**, for those got audit failure in similar situation ?

**EDIT:**

A related post [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364210/low-quality-review-failure-i-dont-understand), the question is not solved. Instead, people have mixed opinions on answers like this. Note on that link, the currently most-voted answer has 33 upvotes, 28 downvotes.

That's why I ask whether it's a good idea to use post like this as an *audit*.

Comment: You should really post only one question per question. Your questions are only tangentially related.

Comment: And personally, I do not think is questionable that "no action needed" is really the wrong choice for that answer. If you are not willing to put in the work for a particular post, just _skip it_.

Comment: @yivi I agree that answer is not good. But it's a problem of degree of "how bad it is". Personally, I found some answers with format like this turn out to be helpful in my experience.Whether it really deserve a *link-only* flag is questionable. See my comment on the answer below.

Comment: It's not really a matter of degree. There were other ways to pass this audit. Clicking "no action needed" was one of the few to actually fail it. This post did need **some** action after all.

Comment: @Patrice It's an answer *with link*, but not *link-only*. I think the first 2 paragraphs in the answer at least look related to the question.

Comment: But the link isn't just supplementary reading material, it's the steps to solve the OP's problem.

Comment: Even if you argue that that answer is not link only, by choosing "no action needed" you are asking for it to be removed from review. And even if you thought that that answer was not link only, you should agree that that needed additional actions in review (comments, edits, votes, etc) to help a first poster to improve their future posts.

Comment: in fact, even a cursory glance shows that the post is spam (compare user name and link this shows self-promotion without properly disclosed affiliation). See also: [How is this a bad answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/361512/839601)

Answer (score 7):

Okay.  I'll give you the benefit of the doubt.

The answer itself does contain *an* answer, or at least the trappings of an answer.  However, the link *doesn't* actually help anything.  It's more or less a plug to their personal GitHub page which "has all the things" you need to solve your problem.

If the meat of their answer was on GitHub, that'd be a problem [given how many DDoSes they've been subject to.](https://www.wired.com/story/github-ddos-memcached/)

The main problem I see is that even *without* the link, the answer isn't all that good anyway.  It becomes more like a comment more than an actual answer.

So yes, *something* had to be done here, but I can at least see how you could get tripped up. Doing *nothing* isn't right since this answer does have a *smell* about it.

<sup>(Oh, by the way - another *very similarly* named account posted the exact same text as an answer, with link.  It was deleted.)</sup>

Comment: The footnote is convincing enough that the answer or account has severe problem. But it's not known to a reviewer. Without this context, this answer is not good, but does it really deserve a flag ? Moreover, even it deserve a flag, should it be *link-only*? As an audit, I think it should be clear enough to every reviewer in general, without much controversy in degree(*"how bad it is"*). This one is kind of questionable.

Comment: So let me get this straight. *This* review is a "delete it!" post because it's essentially link only, but [this review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/364210/1663383) "looks good." Both posts have approximately the same amount of attempt to answer the question and a link that "has the full answer." No freaking wonder people have trouble with these!

Comment: @Draco18s:  At what point in *that* other review post did you see my position change??  I'm one of the guys that said, "No this one's a link-only answer too."

Comment: @liliscent:  This is why I said it had a smell about it.  Something's off.  It's tough at first blush to say or see what definitively.  But taking *no* action is *not* the right thing here.

Comment: @Makoto No no, I didn't mean to imply that *your* position changed. But that if you step back and ignore who is saying what, the *consensus* changes.

Comment: @Draco18s:  I can tell you from looking at the score on that question (it's had over 25 upvotes, go figure the rest ;)) that the consensus is *mixed* at best.  Taking these as hard-and-fast concrete truth is risky since the consensus can still be a bit shaky.  Don't feel bad about asking for clarification.  And we'll get clarification on a few positions soon enough.

Comment: @Draco18s Different review queues have different guidance. Which sometimes contradict each other. Or contradict the guidance for flagging. And yes, it's very confusing. Still, those two answers aren't identical, and in both cases the audit could have been passed by a harder look at the involved posts. In the other case, that post is no longer an audit, thanks to voting, so **that**  problem was fixed.

Comment: @Makoto Maybe as you said, the consensus is mixed. So at least this is not a good candidate for *audit*. AFAIK, reviewing audit is to evaluate whether some people blindly review post. A controversial post with mixed consensus shouldn't be used to impose review ban on users.

Comment: @yivi I didn't mean to imply that the audit could have been passed, that's not the problem. The problem is that the guidance contradicts itself, making it very difficult to learn what is considered "good content." If a one answer is a link only, then the other one should be link only too. If one isn't, then the other isn't. And yes, the other post can no longer be selected for an audit, but only because of the meta effect (and *also* generated its owner +70 rep...) **My point was that the rules are confusing.** Passing an audit is easy, but that's because it's easy to tell that it's an audit!

Comment: @Draco18s As evidenced by the OP (or the other meta-question OP), it is not _that_ easy. Personally, I would have passed this one easily and still disagree with the OP that there is anything controversial about either this reviewed post or what's expected from a reviewer in the FP review queue about a post like this. I'm not convinced that it deletion was the right call, but sure that "no action needed" was the wrong one. And in that sense, audits in different queues should be checking for different things.

Comment: @yivi Its only easy if you do the simple thing of "open the actual post and then look at it there." If it's missing, you need to click "delete" (or close or similar) if its not "looks ok." Many new reviewers don't know this, that's why they have trouble. Sure, once in a while a post gets chosen for an audit and is *legitimately a bad audit.* But that doesn't resolve the issue that there **is no clear guidance on what to do with posts like this one and the other one I linked.** And its posts like these that make *me* avoid the review queues entirely.